# Can we change the admin after creating the Keeper?

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-keepers

Is it possible to give the authority of cancel and withdraw functions to another address after creating the Keeper in the interface? (Admin address) Or is it possible to create a keeper from the contract by giving the desired admin address?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change upkeep admin once it has been created, in case it's needed then the only option is to cancel & reregister upkeep.

At the moment, you can't programmatically register the upkeep.